# Time dependent parameter in AceGen

Tags: acegen, commercial-package

The *AceGen* is a third party *Mathematica* package ([website](http://symech.fgg.uni-lj.si/)) used for the automatic derivation of formulae needed in numerical procedures.

Is there possible to define in *AceGen* code, parameter which will be calculated depending on analysis time increment? If so, how I can do this?

Comment: Hi Bartek and welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: @rhermans I think [consensus](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1995/tags-for-third-party-packages) has been reached that it is ok to ask questions about third-party packages. Tag [tag:acegen] has already around 40 questions and majority of them are of good quality.

Comment: @Pinti I have retracted my vote and deleted the comment just seconds before. I think you are correct, and I was wrong.

Comment: @bartek I am not sure what exactly are you looking for, but of course you can use time increment in AceGen code. You can define it like this: `dt \[RightTee] SMSReal[rdata$$["TimeIncrement"]];`. But please bear in mind that you are likely to get any/better answers if you edit your question with additional information.